# How to get the schema of a database with the DBI package

Tags: r, database-schema, r-dbi

Is there a function in the DBI package to get information about the schema of a database?

I am working with a connection to an SQL Server with the DBI package and the odbc driver. The `dbListTables` functions allows to show the tables in a particular schema with the `schema` parameter, but I cannot find a way to query which schemas there are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the SQL query below.

```
all_schemas <- DBI::dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA")
```

Comment: DBI::dbListObjects(conn) lists the schemata.

Comment: DBI::dbListObjects(conn, Id(schema = "mySchemaName")) lists a specific schema.